# Amp symbol not showing mobile search

Tags: amp-html

Mobile search not showing Amp symbol http://pkmusic.net/ . already checking amp validator pass but why not working. Any one help me How to showing amp symbel my website http://pkmusic.net/

Thanks

Comment: Amp Crawler will take time to crawl the pages.Do you have non amp version for this website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check  [Google Search guidelines for AMP pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6340290?hl=en) to know how get your AMP pages displayed properly in Google Search.

1. Your AMP should follow the [AMP HTML specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec).
2. You should host your AMP page at a URL that makes sense to the user. For instance, if your canonical page is `example.com/giraffes`, you should host the AMP somewhere like `amp.example.com/giraffes` or `example.com/amp/giraffes`, rather than at `test.com/giraffes`.
3. Google will index AMP pages if other pages link to them or [reference](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery) them.
4. Make sure your AMP is [valid](https://search.google.com/search-console/amp).
5. Make sure to [test your structured data](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) and follow [structured data policies](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#structured-data-guidelines).
6. See [Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6328309) which shows a list of successfully indexed AMP pages on your site and any AMP-specific errors found.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have only one page amp and non amp link canonical URL
`code`<link rel="canonical" href="http://pkmusic.net/luv-shv-pyar-vyar-2017-hindi-songs-download/" />`code` 

http://prntscr.com/edipru